# Modern Tribe Event Calendar, change the word "Event" to "Classes", "Venue" to "Location"

Tags: wordpress, events, plugins

I found a way of changing the words “venue” and “organizer” using /httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/the-events-calendar/src/functions/template-tags/venue.php and /httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/the-events-calendar/src/functions/template-tags/organizer.php, but I’d rather make that change in a folder, so they don’t get overwritten when an update comes.

I’d also like to change the word “Events” to “Courses”.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Modern Tribe had a plugin for that purpose.